# Rspec: error in should eq()

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, factory-bot, rspec-rails

Could somebody explain it to me? What is wrong?

```
1) NetworkController GET #index for staff user locates all network latencies to display
 Failure/Error: assigns(:latencies).should eq([@lat1, @lat2, @lat3])

   expected: [#<NetworkLatency from_network_id: "BSC", to_network_id: "FZJ", error_status: nil, percent_packet_lost: 0, min_ping: 54.8, avg_ping: 54.8, max_ping: 54.8, created_at: "2013-07-30 19:09:14", updated_at: "2013-07-30 19:09:14">, #<NetworkLatency from_network_id: "CSC", to_network_id: "ABC", error_status: nil, percent_packet_lost: 0, min_ping: 54.8, avg_ping: 54.8, max_ping: 54.8, created_at: "2013-07-30 19:09:14", updated_at: "2013-07-30 19:09:14">, #<NetworkLatency from_network_id: "CSC", to_network_id: "DEF", error_status: nil, percent_packet_lost: 0, min_ping: 54.8, avg_ping: 54.8, max_ping: 54.8, created_at: "2013-07-30 19:09:14", updated_at: "2013-07-30 19:09:14">]
        got: [#<NetworkLatency from_network_id: "BSC", to_network_id: "FZJ", error_status: nil, percent_packet_lost: 0, min_ping: 54.8, avg_ping: 54.8, max_ping: 54.8, created_at: "2013-07-30 19:09:14", updated_at: "2013-07-30 19:09:14">, #<NetworkLatency from_network_id: "CSC", to_network_id: "ABC", error_status: nil, percent_packet_lost: 0, min_ping: 54.8, avg_ping: 54.8, max_ping: 54.8, created_at: "2013-07-30 19:09:14", updated_at: "2013-07-30 19:09:14">, #<NetworkLatency from_network_id: "CSC", to_network_id: "DEF", error_status: nil, percent_packet_lost: 0, min_ping: 54.8, avg_ping: 54.8, max_ping: 54.8, created_at: "2013-07-30 19:09:14", updated_at: "2013-07-30 19:09:14">]

   (compared using ==)

   Diff:
   @@ -1,4 +1,2 @@
   -[#<NetworkLatency from_network_id: "BSC", to_network_id: "FZJ", error_status: nil, percent_packet_lost: 0, min_ping: 54.8, avg_ping: 54.8, max_ping: 54.8, created_at: "2013-07-30 19:09:14", updated_at: "2013-07-30 19:09:14">,
   - #<NetworkLatency from_network_id: "CSC", to_network_id: "ABC", error_status: nil, percent_packet_lost: 0, min_ping: 54.8, avg_ping: 54.8, max_ping: 54.8, created_at: "2013-07-30 19:09:14", updated_at: "2013-07-30 19:09:14">,
   - #<NetworkLatency from_network_id: "CSC", to_network_id: "DEF", error_status: nil, percent_packet_lost: 0, min_ping: 54.8, avg_ping: 54.8, max_ping: 54.8, created_at: "2013-07-30 19:09:14", updated_at: "2013-07-30 19:09:14">]
   +[#<NetworkLatency from_network_id: "BSC", to_network_id: "FZJ", error_status: nil, percent_packet_lost: 0, min_ping: 54.8, avg_ping: 54.8, max_ping: 54.8, created_at: "2013-07-30 19:09:14", updated_at: "2013-07-30 19:09:14">, #<NetworkLatency from_network_id: "CSC", to_network_id: "ABC", error_status: nil, percent_packet_lost: 0, min_ping: 54.8, avg_ping: 54.8, max_ping: 54.8, created_at: "2013-07-30 19:09:14", updated_at: "2013-07-30 19:09:14">, #<NetworkLatency from_network_id: "CSC", to_network_id: "DEF", error_status: nil, percent_packet_lost: 0, min_ping: 54.8, avg_ping: 54.8, max_ping: 54.8, created_at: "2013-07-30 19:09:14", updated_at: "2013-07-30 19:09:14">]
```

`Expected` and `got` are equal to me. So why Rspec reports an error?

**EDIT**

- I use `eq`
- `created_at` and `udated_at` are created in `schema.rb` by `t.datetime` statements
- NetworkLatency objects are created by FactoryGirl as follows

  `@lat1 = FactoryGirl.create(:network_latency, from_network: @bsc_net, to_network: @fzj_net)`

  `@lat2 = FactoryGirl.create(:network_latency, from_network: @csc_net, to_network: @abc_net)`

  `@lat3 = FactoryGirl.create(:network_latency, from_network: @csc_net, to_network: @def_net)`

  and then fetched from db by controller using:

  `NetworkLatency.where(:from_network_id => site_ids).order('from_network_id ASC, to_network_id ASC')`

Comment: Did you use `eq` or `equal` ?

Answer (score 0):

The test results are indicating that the string representation of the two arrays is the same, but that does not mean that the arrays are `eq` to each other, which requires that each element is `eq` to the corresponding element in the other array. Do you know that the objects are the same in each array? If not, do you know if the objects have a non-standard definition of `==`?

Answer (score 0):

Are those time types actually strings, or are they Ruby's Time type? The latter includes milliseconds and microseconds which are not visible in the string representation; this makes the string representations equal while the times may not be.

For example:

```
2.0.0p0 :001 > Time.now == Time.now
 => false
2.0.0p0 :002 > Time.now.to_s == Time.now.to_s
 => true
2.0.0p0 :003 > puts "%s, %s" % [ Time.now.tv_usec, Time.now.tv_usec]
 247806, 247810
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override `==` operator in your `NetworkLatency` clss:

```
def ==(other)
  self.from_network_id == other.from_network_id && self.to_network_id == other.to_network_id && ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
assigns(:latencies).should match_array([@lat1, @lat2, @lat3])
```

or

```
expect(assigns(:latencies)).to match_array([@lat1, @lat2, @lat3])
```

Answer (score 0):

I was with the same problem. I solved using [timecop](https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop) gem. It freezes the time then you can do the comparisons without interfering time changes.